# How prove $\sup\{|f(x)|:x \in B_X\}=\sup\{f(x):x \in B_X\} $

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove that if $f\in X^*$ and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ then $||f||=\sup\{|f(x)|:x \in B_X\}=\sup\{f(x):x \in B_X\} $ with $B_X$ the unit closed ball centered at $0$.

I have a problem when I try to prove that $\sup\{|f(x)|:x \in B_X\}=\sup\{f(x):x \in B_X\} $. As we have that $f(x)\leq |f(x)|$ then $\sup\{f(x):x \in B_X\} \leq \sup\{|f(x)|:x \in B_X\}$ but I don't know how to prove the other Inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x\in B_X$, set $y=x$ if $f(x)\geq 0$ and $y=-x$ otherwise. Then $y\in B_X$, and
$$ |f(x)|=f(y)\leq \sup\{f(z):z\in B_X\}$$
which yields the opposite inequality by taking the supremum over $x$.